# Fazer login automático em aplicativos híbridos?

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic, session, app-hibrido

fiz um sistema de login que busca usuário no bd,sou novo em desenvolvimento mobile, e queria uma luz (idéia) de como fazer o login de forma automática depois do primeiro acesso. Igual no whatsapp ou face que vc entra com seus dados de login uma vez e depois ele loga sozinho, vc só volta a colocar os dados novamente se vc fizer o logoff. Estou fazendo em ionic, angularjs, php e usei sessões para o login.

grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

Bom, esse objetivo vai depender bastante da forma como você está fazendo a autenticação.

De uma forma geral, um login automático envolve ter alguma informação sobre as credenciais do usuário que permite a autenticação sem uma interação do usuário.

Supondo que seu sistema de autenticação faça uso de tokens, vamos fazer algumas considerações:

```
1) O usuário acessa seu aplicativo, informa o login/senha e seu sistema de autenticação cria um token de acesso para ele.
2) Este token fica armazenado localmente em seu aplicativo e representa o usuário logado.
3) O token só expira quando o usuário clicar em um botão de sair.
```

No seu caso, de forma prática, você poderia armazenar as credenciais do seu sistema de autenticação no LocalStorage do seu aplicativo usando algum serviço do AngularJs. Toda vez que seu usuário acessar seu aplicativo, você poderia conferir se as informações existem ali e fazer o login automaticamente.

Outra vez, tudo depende da forma de autenticação escolhida. Mas a grosso modo, seria por aí.

Answer (score 1):

No meu app, quando eu faço o login eu guardo o usuário que logou no localstorage do browser. Quando o usuário abre a aplicação de novo, eu só faço uma checagem pra verificar se tem algum usuário guardado nesse localstorage, se tiver eu direciono pra primeira tela do meu app, senão, eu redireciono pra tela de login.

Em termos de código seria assim:

**No seu controller do login**

```
//você deve estar fazendo algo assim
$http.post("http://suaUrl", dadosDoUsuário).success(function(user)) {
    localStorage.setItem("user", user); //primeiro parâmetro é o nome desse localStorage, e o segundo é o objeto usuário.
}
```

No app.js, dentro do .run, você faz:

**App.js**

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state) { //atente para adicionar o $state
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() { 
      var user = localStorage.getItem("user");

          if(user !== "undefined" && user !== "null") {
             $state.go("suaPaginaPrincipal");
          } else {
                $state.go("suaPaginaDeLogin");
          }
   });
})
```